# Create web presentation with animations from powerpoint file

Tags: html, animation, powerpoint, interactive, presentation

I hope it is possible to make this question, I am new in this field and I would like to receive some advice.
I have a Power Point presentation with some animations, video etc and I have to create a web page where user can see this presentation and interact with some object in the sheet.
I have no idea how it could be done, I read several guide on the web, one way seems to be use of ppt to html5 converter, is it the right way (I need a free tool in this case)? to start I have to create a demo with few pages and animations, what do you suggest?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to host your presentation on a site that lets people view it directly in the browser.

http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/share/share-ppt-using-web-viewer.html

In this one, note that SkyDrive is now called OneDrive:

http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/ppweb/embed-powerpoint-on-your-blog-or-site.html